# JavaScript/React - Update a value in array with particular key name from a array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecma

In the below array of arrays I need to update the **id** value for a particular **name**.

```
objArray = [{ name: John, id: 12}, { name: Jake, id: 45}, { name: Jacob, id: 78}];
```

Ex: If user enters a name and id in text boxes and clicks submit I want to update the id in the array for the particular name.

I can accomplish this using for loops but can you please let me know the most efficient way to do this in Java Script/React?

Comment: The duplicate shows you how to find the object in the array. From there you just need to update its `name` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `find` function and set the entered name.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
let objArray = [{  name: "John",  id: 12}, {  name: "Jake",  id: 45}, {  name: "Jacob",  id: 78}];

let name = 'Jake'
let newId = 59;
objArray.find((o) => o.name === name).id = newId;

console.log(objArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it the other way around. Update the id for a particular name.

Comment: @Skyler oops, you're right!

Comment: Thank you! this solved it. Simple and elegant.

Comment: @Nitheesh you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` to get the index of the object whose name matches. Then use that index to update the id

```js
var objArray = [{
  name: 'John',
  id: 12
}, {
  name: 'Jake',
  id: 45
}, {
  name: 'Jacob',
  id: 78
}];

function update() {
  var getVal = document.getElementById('ip').value.trim();
  var getIndex = objArray.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name.toLowerCase() === getVal.toLowerCase();
  })
  objArray[getIndex].id= "newId"
  console.log(objArray)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ip">
<button onclick="update()">Update</button>
```

Comment: Thanks brk! This solved my problem too but I would go with Ele's answer. I want to give you a one up but I dont have enough reps!